# Inserting data in mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data in existing row i know how to fill table using php code like this:

`"INSERT INTO table (name, email, surname)VALUES('{$name}','{$email}','{$surname}')";`

And my situation is that once i create it i want to add more extra info for the specific name. For example if i have created row in table in the name Josh and later i want to add his phone number. Basically my question is how can i edit table row once it is created? How can i add this extra info?

Comment: If you are looking at how to update rows in a database table, there are plenty of good tutorials already available for php.  If you have a more specific question that those tutorials don't answer, you can ask it (but only after you search for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `update` statement, look at syntax

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

```
UPDATE table
SET phone_number=value, ...
WHERE name="Josh"
```

but you need to have created such column in your table